# Change MySql root password

Tags: password, mysql

Is this correct to change the root password of MySql?

```
echo "use mysql; update user set password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") where User='root'; flush privileges; quit;" | mysql -u root -pOLDPASSWORD
```

I've seen [this doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html) and a few others, but I don't find one "simple" definitive answer in a few lines.

Also, should I stop `mysql` server before doing it, and restarting it after? (I tried `mysql stop` or `mysql -uroot -pOLDPASSWORD stop` on my Debian but none of them worked).

---

Note: `mysql -V` gives `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper command to do so is:

```
mysql -uroot -poldp4ssw0rd -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newp4ssw0rd');"
```

assuming that *oldp4ssw0rd* and *newp4ssw0rd* are the old and new passwords.

You do not need to stop or restart the MySQL server at any time. In fact, the service needs to be running for you to connect to it and issue the command above.

Note: this command solves your problem; however, in general it is not a good idea to pass passwords as command line arguments, as they could be seen by other logged-in users.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the same password than when using `update user set password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") where User='root'`? Also what command do you usually use to restart? `service mysql restart`?

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) Yes, if you're using Debian or RHEL6. `/etc/init.d/mysql restart` also works.